# Xcode doesn't automatically create viewDidLoad method

Tags: xcode, templates, viewdidload, didreceivememorywarning

When I create a subclass of `UIViewController`, Xcode doesn't automatically create `viewDidLoad` method and `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method. Why did this happen? What should I do to make it work normal?

Comment: Please show your code that creates the subclass and the one which causes unexpected behaviour. Please also explain what behaviour is expected and what actually happens.

Comment: Remember that your issue should be reproducible from your description.

Comment: When i user ⌘N create a new Cocoa Class file, and make a new Class which is Subclass of UIViewController. When it work right, it will automatically create viewDidLoad & didreceiveMemoryWaring method, but it suddenly don't.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are choosing "Cocoa **Touch** Class" (from the **iOS** section of templates) and ***not*** "Cocoa Class" (from the **macOS / OSX** section of templates) when creating the new file.